# How to close window left button of mouse?

Tags: javascript

I have some popups  and now they close if i press any mouse button. I need only left mouse to press and close popup

And the 2nd one question. Why esc popup  code doesnt work??

```js
    const overlayClose = (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
            togglePopup(evt.target);
        }
    }
    editPopup.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
        overlayClose(evt);
    });
    addPopup.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
        overlayClose(evt);
    });
    imagePopup.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
        overlayClose(evt);
    });
    
    
    //popup esc code
function togglePopup(popup) {
    popup.classList.toggle('popup_active');
    if (popup.classList.contains('popup_active')) {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', closeEscape);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeEscape);
    }
}


const closeEscape = (evt) => {
    if (evt.key === "Escape") {
        popup.classList.remove('popup_active');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @hev1
https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/ExKjPwa

Comment: @Ivar Yes. But i still dont understand how can i use that in my code

Comment: @Иваниванов Put the code from that function (without the return line) at the top of your event listeners and put the `button == 1` inside an  if-statement condition. Everything in the if-statement will only be executed if you left-click.

Answer (score 0):

Here's useful docs about mouse click events
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_button.asp

You can add event listener on 'mousedown' event and check if `event.button` equals 0.

#### UPD

You simply need to add `if` condition in your event handlers

```
 editPopup.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
    if (evt.button === 0) {
      overlayClose(evt);
    }
 });
```